# Unable to boot SunOS 5.8

Tags: solaris, sunos

I had to hard reboot a SunOS 5.8 server due to a networking fault. On giving 'boot' command on OK prompt, I get the following messages

```
Can't read disk label. Can't open disk label package Boot device:
secondary File and args: Can't read disk label. Can't open disk 
label package

Can't open boot device
```

I am unable to run fsck on OK prompt. How should I go about troubleshooting this error?

Its a Sun Enterprise E3500 running SunOS 5.8

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like the disk may be dead. I would start by booting from alternate media (e.g. an install cd) to get a shell prompt and perform some diagnostics.